# Show that $|\Gamma| = \lim_{\sigma \to 0}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{|\mu(t_{k+1})-\mu(t_k)|}}$ for $\Gamma$ curve on complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, curves

Show that $|\Gamma| = \lim_{\sigma \to 0}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{|\mu(t_{k+1})-\mu(t_k)|}}$ for $\Gamma$ curve on complex plane, where $\Gamma: \{\mu,[\alpha,\beta]\}, \sigma = max\{t_{k+1}-t_k\}$. By book has defined that $|\Gamma| = \sup\{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{|\mu(t_{k+1})-\mu(t_k)|}\}$. Also, it is obvious that $\lim_{\sigma \to 0}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{|\mu(t_{k+1})-\mu(t_k)|}} \leq |\Gamma|$, because $|\Gamma|$ doesn't depend on $\sigma$. Yet I can't show that $|\Gamma| \leq \lim_{\sigma \to 0}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{|\mu(t_{k+1})-\mu(t_k)|}}$

Comment: Hint: Show that If $P$ and $Q$ are partitions of an interval $[a,b]$ and $P\subset Q$ then $\sum_{t_j\in P}|\mu(t_{j+1})=\mu(t_j)|\leq \sum_{u_k\in Q}|\mu(u_{k+1})=\mu(u_k)|$

Comment: @OliverDíaz ohh now I remember it it's the same logic as when defining integrals. Thanks

Comment: Indeed. The variation with $|\;|$ can be dealt similar to that of Riemann integration. For  higher order variations $|\;|^p$ with $p>1$ is a different story.